# When statement kotlin greater than or equals

Tags: kotlin

In kotlin `when` statement I can do `in 2..4` which is equivalent to `>= 2` and `<= 4`.

How do I just look for `>= 2`? I tried an infinite range: `in 2..`, but this doesn't seem to be a thing.

I also tried just putting in `>= 2`, but no luck either.

How do I do this in kotlin? Or do I have to switch to an if statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be

```
in 2..Integer.MAX_VALUE
```

Assumed your values are integers, as you are looking for an iterable range.

Answer (score 3):

What was the problem with `>=`?

This works fine:

```
val x = 3
val y = when {
    x + 1 >= 4 -> "one"
    x + 1 < 4 -> "two"
    else -> "else"
}
println(y)
```

Comment: This requires me to repeat the value in each clause. I didn't even realize you could do that with `when` in kotlin. Good to know anyway thanks.